# "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" dialogue system in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i know many people have asked this question already but i cant seem to fix the error even if i look actively and experiment on many types of codes that i have seen or used. What im trying to achieve is that when i get inside a room the dialogue system will pop up automatically. Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class McroomDialogueTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public McRoomDialogue dialogue;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        TriggerDialogue();
    }

    public void TriggerDialogue()
    {
        FindObjectOfType<McroomDialogueManager>().StartDialogues(dialogue);
    }
}
```

This is the code script that is getting errors. I used this before in the first scene of my game and just used different variables on this one. The other one was not working at first and i left it for a sec and it just suddenly became ok. Im confused, can you guys please help me i would very much appreciate it so much.

Comment: Presumably `FindObjectOfType<McroomDialogueManager>()` is `null`.

Comment: How can i make it not null?

Comment: By making sure a GameObject exists in the scene with a `McroomDialogueManager` component attached ...

Comment: @derHugo the object exist but i still cant get it to work

Comment: Is it active in the Hierarchy and the component enabled? (Both is required for `FindObjectOfType` to find the instance